# Community SQLite Plugin for MvvmCross

Tags: sqlite, plugins, mvvmcross

I am trying to use/install the Community SQLite plugin. Using nuget everything seems to install OK, e.g I get no errors. However,in my Core project there are no references to the plugin.

In the iOS and Android references there are references to the plugin.

Do I need to reference the plugin explicitly in my Core project.

Has anyone else got this working. Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to add the plugin in the core, you should see in the youtube stuartlodge videos about using mvvmcross
https://www.youtube.com/user/MrHollywoof/videos

Comment: Hi Daniel. I have added it via Nuget to the core project. There are no references to the plugin added to the project references list. Do you mean something else by adding the plugin in core?